# ASP.NET - configuring a feature so QA can test it

Tags: asp.net, configuration

I'm building a feature in our ASP.NET application where the feature is simply a background service that runs and deletes some old data. I'm using a System.Timers.Timer to run the service every 12 hours.

My question is, **how can I build this so that QA can properly test the feature**? Obviously I cannot expect QA to wait 12 hours to ensure the feature works.

Some ideas:

- Have the timer elapsed configurable
  in a config file.
- Have some hidden
  page that QA could load that would
  run the feature.
- Have the timer
  configured differently for QA builds
  (e.g. run every 15 secs on QA builds)

What's a good way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the timer elapsed period configurable.

QA will be able to test:

1. The timer works correctly (they can test different periods).
2. The work done is the correct work.

Comment: If I stick it in a config file, won't QA have to restart the app in IIS each time they want to test the feature?

Comment: @Judah Himango - If this is a `web.config`, the web app will automatically restart every time it is changed. I would say they can test it on _one_ configuration for a while.

Comment: Are you sure about this? I added the timer interval to web.config, but editing the web.config file on my dev box doesn't seem to restart the app. Global.asax has the Application_Start handler; it never gets called when editing the web.config file. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @Judah Himango - It should restart as soon as you save the file. This may not be the case if you are using the dev web server.